# Header and navigation aren't at the same line (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML and CSS from one guy tutorials and I have a problem. I want that my navigation and heading would be at one line, but when I type display: inline; it doesn't do anything.

Here's the photo:

[image]

My HTML and CSS: http://pastebin.com/uZunJFr7

Any help?

Comment: Please post your code here along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting rules for `nav ul` instead of `nav`, which is the sibling of `h1` in your code, and is the one that needs to line up with it. Also, use `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzhg4cof/

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
header h1 {
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
}
```

heres a fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/dnqxLwkp/